# add minutes to timestamp- most efficient way

Tags: java, timestamp

I have to write a java code to add minutes(delayminutes) to a timestamp(tmpTimeStamp). This is what I have. I was wondering if this is an efficient way to do this or if there is a better way.

```
long t=tmpTimeStamp.getTime();
long m=delayMinutes*60*1000;
targetDeliveryStamp= new Timestamp(t+m);
```

Comment: This is perfectly fine, but the question is probably more a code review questions, as youre not really having a problem (I did not flag, just an advice)

Comment: I will keep this in mind in future. Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's pretty good.  You can be slightly more efficient and avoid object construction overhead if you can reuse your temporary Timestamp:

```
tmpTimeStamp.setTime(tmpTimeStamp.getTime() + TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(delayMinutes));
```

Comment: I think it is kind of a mutual agreement that TimeStamp should be immutable, so i think OPs Version is actually better (from a design perspective)